# Value of put if underlying stays below strike?

Tags: put-options

If ABC stock is trading at $5 and I buy the Jan 15 strike put for $8.25, what happens to the value of this put at expiration if ABC only meandered between $5 to $7 during the entire period?

Comment: What is the strike of the put? $8.25 is quite expensive for a put price, is this supposed to be the strike price?

Comment: I think he means the $15 strike.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - no I think the expiry is Jan 2015. Anyway, the question as it is not very clear.

Comment: not enough information without the strike price

Comment: @victor - right. A $15 strike means $10 in the money for a $5 stock. He needs to spell this out, the strike he bought.

Comment: It is Jan with 15 strike.  I've updated the question.

Comment: You do realize that a put is the opportunity to sell at that price while in contrast a call option would be to buy at that price, right?

Comment: @JBKing haha I didn't even consider this possible assumption oh man. I did think it was peculiar to buy a put more expensive than the stock with so little downside left in the stock!

Comment: As I noted to Victor - A $15 strike put has $10 "in the money" value what the stock is $5. It will not sell for $8.25/

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer If this is a *European* put, it theoretically could trade for $8.25 depending on the local interest rate.

Comment: @4thSpace - can you add your country as a tag ?

Answer (score 1):

The value at expiration does not depend on the price path for a plain vanilla European or American option. At expiration, the value would simply be:

max[K - S_T, 0],

where: K is the strike price,

and S_T is the underlying price at expiration.

Answer (score 0):

$15 - $5 = $10

How did you possibly buy a put for less than the intrinsic value of the option, at $8.25

So we can infer that you would have had to get this put when the stock price was AT LEAST $6.75, but given the 3 months of theta left, it was likely above $7

The value of the put if the price of the underlying asset (the stock ABC) meandered between $5 - $7 would be somewhere between $10 - $8 at expiration.

So you don't really stand to lose much in this scenario, and can make a decent gain in this scenario. I mean decent if you were trading stocks and were trying to beat the S&P or keep up with Warren Buffett, but a pretty poor gain since you are trading options!

If the stock moves above $7 this is where the put starts to substantially lose value.